# Dataset with similar data points, but some of the targets are different

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, feature-engineering

I have a df:

```
  gender    category    subcategory  item_brand   item_NWT  item_price
   Women    Outerwear     Jacket      J. Crew        NWT       22.0
   Women    Outerwear     Jacket      Talbots        NWT       50.0
   Women    Outerwear     Jacket      J. Crew        NWT       100.0
```

I have some features with similar values and different target price, I get the feeling the my model will perform poorly by have this type of data right?. Also some similar features have the same target price, the thing is: it's my first time dealing with an issue like this one.

Comment: In reality you either have noise/measurement error in the value of item_price, causing it to differ for seemingly identical rows, or there are features that you don't observe in your data that lead to those actual differences. Which one (or combination) of these you believe, and exactly what you are trying to model will determine what kind of problems you'll have

Comment: I just asked to my client, because in case there is not an additional feature to make the price be different, maybe the price data is wrong. I am pretty sure the subcategory column should be more specific in other to have different price.